# Add a button to tinyMCE editor on Custom Post Type

Tags: tinymce

How do I go about adding a simple button to tinymce on the default editor area of my new Custom Post Type?

I'd like the button, when clicked, to ask for a text value. The script should then `lowercase` the input and replace spaces with hyphens, and insert `[glossary=value-entered]` into the editor.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this tutorial on Pro Blog Design: http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/user-friendly-short-codes-with-tinymce/

Comment: That is a tutorial and a half... ! Thanks very much, looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this?

http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

Comment: I actually hadn't. Is that up to date? Is it simply a case of writing a tinyMCE plugin then using that WP code to load it?

Comment: That is up to date.

It is as you say, writing a TinyMCE plugin and calling that with the WP code. That is how I've done it in the past.